# Preload Problem

Tags: jquery

How can I make preload images in the slider?.

My Codes;

```
var uploader = $('#flashUploader').pluploadQueue();     
    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, response) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response.response); 
            $('#slides div div').append("<img src='http://www.smyrnart.com/upl/1282314.jpg'>")
            **After Upload I Want to Preload here.**
});
```

I am use https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides/blob/master/source/slides.js.

Thank for answers.

Comment: What do you mean by preload here?

Comment: Preload event in slides.js. But I can't use after upload. I want to make $("#slides").slides("preload"); after $('#slides div div').append("<img src='http://www.smyrnart.com/upl/1282314.jpg'>") this code.

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* you want to upload an image and display it in the slider afterwards. I think preloading in slides.js is for preloading the images on initialization of the DOM. But at the time you upload your image the DOM is already initialized.

What you may want to do is instantiate the plugin when your upload is finished.